# What properties do i need to order a dedicated host server unsing the Java API?

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I am trying to order dedicated Host using JAVA API
(verifyorder and placeorder method)

To order the product, What properties do i need ?

Comment: This question is not sufficient. Please provide example code of what you have attempted so far, and the specific area you need help with. You need to provide quite a bit more detail to this question before anyone will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the package 813 to order a dedicated host, set the router backend and pass the item price of configuration you want. Bellow is an example.

```java
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Hardware;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.order.Receipt;
import com.softlayer.api.service.hardware.Router;
import com.softlayer.api.service.network.Component;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.Order;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.item.Price;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class OrderDedicatedHost {

    public OrderDedicatedHost(){
        // Declare username and api key
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Declare required variables to place an order
        long quantity = 1;
        String location = "MEXICO";
        long packageId = 813;

        // Declare router you want to use on dedicated host
        Router router = new Router();
        router.setId(329266L);

        // Vlans need to be into network components
        Component primaryBackendNetworkComponent = new Component();
        primaryBackendNetworkComponent.setRouter(router);

        // Set hostname, domain and network components of Hardware you want to order
        List<Hardware> hardwareList = new ArrayList<Hardware>();
        Hardware hardware = new Hardware();
        hardware.setHostname("dedicatedHost");
        hardware.setDomain("domaintest.local");
        hardware.setPrimaryBackendNetworkComponent(primaryBackendNetworkComponent);

        hardwareList.add(hardware);

        // Build the skeleton of SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price objects
        List<Price> priceList = new ArrayList<Price>();
        Price price = new Price();
        price.setId(200269L);   // 56 Cores X 242 RAM X 1.2 TB

        priceList.add(price);

        // Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order object template that will be used to order Dedicated Host.
        com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.Order orderTemplate = new com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.Order();
        orderTemplate.setLocation(location);
        orderTemplate.setPackageId(packageId);
        orderTemplate.setQuantity(quantity);
        orderTemplate.getHardware().addAll(hardwareList);
        orderTemplate.getPrices().addAll(priceList);

        // Get Api Client and service
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        Order.Service orderService = Order.service(client);

        try{
            // verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with placeOrder() when
            // you're ready to order:
            //     Receipt receipt = orderService.placeOrder(orderTemplate, Boolean.FALSE);
            com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.Order receipt = orderService.verifyOrder(orderTemplate);

            // Print response in JSON format
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(receipt));

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to place the order : " + e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new OrderDedicatedHost();
    }
}
```

I recommend to review the service [SoftLayer_Virtual_DedicatedHost](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_DedicatedHost) if you want to work with this device through the API, for example, the method [SoftLayer_Virtual_DedicatedHost::getAvailableRouters](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Virtual_DedicatedHost/getAvailableRouters) could help you to know what router you can set during order. Following is example to get available router that supports a dedicated host with 56 Cores X 242 RAM X 1.2 TB

```js
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Hardware;
import com.softlayer.api.service.Location;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.DedicatedHost;

import java.util.List;

public class GetAvailableRouter {

    public GetAvailableRouter(){
        // Declare username and api key
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Use the method SoftLayer_Location::getDatacenters in order to get location ids.
        Location location = new Location();
        location.setId(449600L);

        // Skeleton of the dedicated host to specify the data center and configuration sizes
        // 56 Cores X 242 RAM X 1.2 TB
        DedicatedHost template = new DedicatedHost();
        template.setCpuCount(56L);
        template.setDiskCapacity(1200L);
        template.setMemoryCapacity(242L);
        template.setDatacenter(location);

        // Get Api Client and service
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        DedicatedHost.Service service = DedicatedHost.service(client);

        try{
            // Get list of available routers
            List<Hardware> routers = service.getAvailableRouters(template);

            // Print response in JSON format
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(routers));

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to get the backend routers: " + e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new GetAvailableRouter();
    }
}
```

To order a VSI on an specific dedicated host you need to set the **hostId** in the [SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/datatypes/SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest) container, and specify prices like cpu, ram and uplink that supports dedicated hosts.

**Note:** The hostId is the id of dedicated host you ordered before. You can also use the method [SoftLayer_Account::getDedicatedHosts](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Account/getDedicatedHosts) to get the list of dedicated hosts.

```js
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import com.softlayer.api.ApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.RestApiClient;
import com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.order.Receipt;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.Order;
import com.softlayer.api.service.product.item.Price;
import com.softlayer.api.service.virtual.Guest;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class orderVsiOnDedicatedHost {

    public orderVsiOnDedicatedHost(){
        // Declare username and api key
        String username = "set me";
        String apiKey = "set me";

        // Declare required variables to place an order
        long quantity = 1;
        long packageId = 46;
        long hostId = 48501L;

        // Declare hostname, domain and network components of guests you want to order, add more guest objects if
        // quantity is greater than 1
        List<Guest> virtualGuests = new ArrayList<Guest>();
        Guest guest = new Guest();
        guest.setHostname("vsiOnDedicatedHost");
        guest.setDomain("domaintest.local");

        virtualGuests.add(guest);

        // Declare the list of prices. To get list of all available prices you can use the method
        // SoftLayer_Product_Package::getItemPrices
        long[] pricesIds = {
                200307,    // 1 x 2.0 GHz Cores (Dedicated Host)
                200337,    // 1 GB RAM (Dedicated Host)
                45466,    // CentOS 7.x - Minimal Install (64 bit)
                2202,     // "25 GB (SAN) as First disk
                1800,     // 0 GB Bandwidth
                203857,   // 100 Mbps Public & Private Network Uplinks (Dedicated Host)
                55,       // Monitoring - Host Ping
                57,       // Email and Ticket
                58,       // Automated Notification
                21,       // Primary IP Addresses
                418,      // Nessus Vulnerability Assessment & Reportin
                420,      // VPN Management - Private Network
                905       // Remote Management
        };

        // Building the skeleton of SoftLayer_Product_Item_Price objects
        List<Price> prices = new ArrayList<Price>();
        for (int i = 0; i < pricesIds.length; i++) {
            Price p = new Price();
            p.setId(pricesIds[i]);
            prices.add(p);
        }

        // Build a skeleton SoftLayer_Container_Product_Order_Virtual_Guest object template that will be used to order VSIs.
        com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.order.virtual.Guest orderTemplate = new com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.order.virtual.Guest();
        orderTemplate.setHostId(hostId);
        orderTemplate.setPackageId(packageId);
        orderTemplate.setQuantity(quantity);
        orderTemplate.getVirtualGuests().addAll(virtualGuests);
        orderTemplate.getPrices().addAll(prices);
        orderTemplate.setUseHourlyPricing(Boolean.TRUE);

        // Get Api Client and service
        ApiClient client = new RestApiClient().withCredentials(username, apiKey);
        Order.Service orderService = Order.service(client);

        try{
            // verifyOrder() will check your order for errors. Replace this with placeOrder() when
            // you're ready to order:
            //             Receipt receipt = orderService.placeOrder(orderTemplate, Boolean.FALSE);
            com.softlayer.api.service.container.product.Order receipt = orderService.verifyOrder(orderTemplate);

            // Print response in JSON format
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();
            System.out.println(gson.toJson(receipt));

        } catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println("Unable to place the order: " + e);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String [] args)
    {
        new orderVsiOnDedicatedHost();
    }
}
```